# 'bounds' doesn't work in scipy.stats.minimize function

Tags: python, scipy

I had a very strange problem in the minimize function. I wrote following code and hoped to output result from (0,1).

```
cons = ({'type':'eq','fun':lambda x: 1-sum(x)})
bnds = [(0,1)]*len(w)
minS = minimize(min_S_function, w, method = 'SLSQP', bounds = bnds, constraints = cons)
```

However, the result output many extremely small numbers instead of zero even though I set bounds between 0 to 1. Why is that?

```
In [68]:minS.x
Out[68]: 
array([  2.18674802e-14,  -2.31905438e-14,   4.05696128e-01,
     1.61295198e-14,   4.98954818e-02,  -2.75073615e-14,
     3.97195447e-01,   1.09796187e-14,  -4.33297358e-15,
     2.38805100e-14,   7.73037793e-15,   3.21824430e-14,
    -1.42202909e-14,  -1.08110329e-14,  -1.83513297e-14,
    -1.37745269e-14,   3.37854385e-14,   4.69473932e-14,
    -1.09088800e-15,  -1.57169147e-14,   7.47784562e-02,
     1.32782180e-02,   1.64441640e-14,   2.72140153e-15,
     5.23069695e-14,   5.91562687e-02,   2.16467506e-15,
    -6.50672519e-15,   2.53337977e-15,  -6.68019297e-14])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an acceptable solution!

Those iterative solvers only guarantee a local-optimum approximate-solution and that's what you got!

Check your numbers and you will see, that the distance to the lower-bound (of your negative out-of-bound values) is within `10^-14 = 0,00000000000001`, an acceptable error (we use floating-point math after all).